# Iterate through an image list with 5 seconds time gap

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scripting

I have an array of urls containing locations of pictures on page load. I need to show them to the user in an `<asp:img>` with a 5 second time interval.

Can this be done with `<asp:timer>`, or is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Image ID="image1" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">
var imgArray = ['1.png','2.png','3.png','4.png','5.png','6.png','7.png','8.png','9.png','10.png'], imgToShow = 0;

function showImage() {
   if(imgToShow > imgArray.length - 1)
      imgToShow = 0;

   document.getElementById("<%= image1.ClientID %>").src = imgArray[imgToShow++];
}

showImage();
window.setInterval(showImage, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: hey!! thank you very much. This is really helpful to me to extend and update more fields rather than only images....

Answer (score 1):

Try using a javascript plugin for that. [Coin slider](http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/) is great for this.

Comment: that's great if I have only images to iterate through. What if I need to change some details in other controls, for example say text in a label?

Comment: I dont' quite get what you're asking. Can you please restate?

Comment: what about updating labels after 5 seconds(not only images, which can be easily done using Coin Slider as you said...)

Comment: In that case, check the answer by AlbertVanHalen.

Answer (score 0):

Create for loop and iterate trough array, how else would you do it?

Comment: @Asanka how big is your array

Comment: @Asanka than the for loop will do for that